# How can I install QtWebEngine on Ubuntu

Tags: git, qt, ubuntu, qml, qtwebengine

When a QML program (e.g. Ethereum, [installed from the PPA](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) in this case) tries to

```
import QtWebEngine 1.0
import QtWebEngine.experimental 1.0
```

Then I get these errors

```
file:////usr/share/mist/qml/views/browser.qml:5 module "QtWebEngine" is not installed
file:////usr/share/mist/qml/views/browser.qml:6 module "QtWebEngine.experimental" is not installed
```

QtWebEngine is in [Qt 5.4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) which is what I have installed

```
#> qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I tried to [build QtWebEngine myself](http://www.ics.com/blog/building-qtwebengine) but no joy:

```
#> git clone git@gitorious.org:qt-labs/qtwebengine.git
Cloning into 'qtwebengine'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

1) Why isn't QtWebEngine installed if it's in Qt 5.4, which *is* installed?

2) Is there a way to install it other than building it myself?

3) What is wrong with the `git clone` command?

Thanks for reading. I'm doing this on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: You should really ask whoever supplied the deb package in that PPA, clearly they got their dependencies incorrect.

Comment: Packages were being upgraded, which takes a few hours in the case of Qt. Clearly you didn't look into it any further before commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specific to Ethereum and the [ethereum-qt PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum-qt/+packages), which was being upgraded from Qt 5.4.0 to 5.4.1, something that takes many hours to complete. Just `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and everything should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I ran those commands just now, a whole bunch of qt packages did update, but I get exactly the same errors launching mist.

Comment: Try `apt-get dist-upgrade`, since following the instructions you linked to works here(tm) and was reported to work by many others.

Answer (score 2):

I found that another cause of this 'module "Qt*" is not installed' class of problems on Ubuntu at least is the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` not being set. It should include the path to the lib directory of your Qt installation, e.g.

```
if [ "x$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "x" ]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/lib
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
```