# How to install QtWebEngine on Ubuntu 14.04 as dev dependency?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qtwebengine

I have an app that I made with Qt and it can be run without installing Qt Creator by just installing the dev dependencies on Linux such as:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
sudo apt-get install libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
```

I upgraded the app from Qt 5.2 to 5.7 and now it uses QtWebEngine and QtWebEgineWidgets. My problem is that when I run qmake and make for the upgraded app I get the error message

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

I've been trying to find a way to install webEngineWidgets as a dev dependency on Linux just like webkitWidgets but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I've read [How can I install QtWebEngine on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088564/how-can-i-install-qtwebengine-on-ubuntu) but my problem is different since I don't want to install Qt Creator.

Is there a way to install QtWebEngineWidgets as a dev dependency?